# Callback inside JS Object Not Working on JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

**UPDATE**: With help, I was able to tracked down the issue. It was the if(!actions) that was doing something to the function reference. Once I remove the '!', it worked. It was a bug on my part as I wanted to check if it has a reference in the first place. My new question is what did that ! operator do to the function that would cause it to evaluate to true and then alter the reference that it cause the function to fail (in this case no errors in the debugger was detected)?

**Original:**
I created a javascript function that encapsulate some variables and perform a callback when a JQuery UI dialog button is clicked. Here is the javascript for the function:

```
function LoginControl(parentDiv, usernameInput, passwordInput, action)
{
    var that = this;
    var container = parentDiv;
    var user = usernameInput;
    var password = passwordInput;
    var actions = action;

    that.init = function()
    {
        container.dialog(
            {
                modal:true,
                show:false,
                buttons: {"Login":Login, Cancel:Close }
            }
        );
    };

    var Login = function (evt) {
        if (!actions)
            actions();
    };

    var Close = function()
    {
        container.dialog("close");
        if(!actions)
            actions();
    };

    that.show = function(evt)
    {
        container.dialog("open");
    };
}
```

The problem is in the Login/Close function where it executes the actions function. When it executes, the debugger gives me this warning "Ignoring get or set of property that has [LenientThis] because the "this" object is incorrect.". The function is not executed. Here is the HTML (I omitted the external jquery source files, but I am using JQuery 2.0.3 and JQuery UI 1.1.3. I cannot figure this out and have been bothered by it. I have tried using the "call", "bind", and "apply" method to no avail. Please help and advise. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onAction()
        {
            alert("Hello!");
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var loginCtrl = new LoginControl($("#login"), $("#username"), $("#pass"), onAction);

            loginCtrl.init();
            loginCtrl.show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="login">
    <form>
        <label for="username">User Name:</label> <input type="text" id="username" /><br>
        <label for="pass">Password:</label><input type="password" id="pass" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Login` and `Close` to `that.Login =` and `that.Close =`. They are currently variables inside the function, not visible to the outside. Also change `buttons: {"Login":Login, Cancel:Close }` to `buttons: {"Login":that.Login, Cancel:that.Close }`

Comment: That did not work. Yielded the same result. When I inspected the actions variable, in the debugger, it shows it as a function. When it executed, the watch shows that it had a return value of undefined, which it was already doing before the change you suggested. As a curiosity, I decided to create the onAction function within the LoginControl function and called that instead of the actions variable. That worked fined. But when I assigned actions to the onAction function in the init, it was back to square one. At this point I think its a scope issue, but I lost as to how to rectify it.

Comment: I forgot to add, you need to change `var actions = action;` to `that.actions = action` and then call action as `that.actions();`. Can you try these as well together with the changes in the answer?

Comment: I made the modification you suggested, but its yielding the same result.

Comment: Can you copy paste this to your console and see what you get? -->  `function f1(act){
  
  var that = this;
  that.acts = act;
  console.log(that.acts);
  
  that.callActs = function(){
    that.acts();
  }
};

function f2(){
  console.log("f2 here");
}

var f1 = new f1(f2);
f1.callActs();`

Comment: @stn9000 Did you get anything with the code in the previous comment?

Comment: Ok, I pasted the code in. The console output is as follows: f2() f2 here.

Comment: @stn9000 So f1 calls the callback. Have you checked the code? It's the same as what you're doing, yeah?

Comment: The code is the same and actually cleaner to experiment with. I modified it to pass in the document object as well and hook up a click event to call the acts function as a callback. So far it is yielding good result. I will try to apply it to what I was originally doing and update this once I am done. thanks!